# How can I shard a Discord bot in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I've been looking everywhere from the past few days and I can't really figure out how I could implement sharding in a discord bot. I have tried looking in the documentation but couldn't find anything that would explain how to implement it.

I'm using discord.py by the way

Comment: does this help you? https://maah.gitbooks.io/discord-bots/content/sharding.html

Comment: @cbracketdash Thats in JavaScript, not Python

Comment: yea but can you use the concepts for python?

Comment: How do we pass in a variable to the shard_count if we can't grab the number of guilds until on_ready? This is called before on_ready because client has to be defined in order to call the client event

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a normal client, you should create an `AutoShardedClient()`:

`client = discord.AutoShardedClient(shard_count=10)`

See the [relevant documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.AutoShardedClient).

Comment: Hm ok I see. But how, for example can you make your bot run on multiple servers with sharding?

Answer (score 1):

Like @Bharel wrote change your normal client to `AutoShardedClient()`, but I suggest using this:

```
client = commands.AutoShardedBot(shard_count=10, command_prefix="??") #with this you can easily choose one prefix for all bots that were sharded
```